# Looping through template items in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm still new to Angular and am having a hard time updating items in an elegant way. I have the following code :

```
 <div class="curative col-md-3" ng-repeat="c in curatives">
        <span class="title">{{c.name}}</span>
        <input class="equ" />
        <input class="for" />
</div>
```

And in my app, I have this

```
$scope.curatives = [
    {'name': 'Curative 1'},
    {'name': 'Curative 2'}
];
```

No problem so far. Now I want to show a summary of the values in the different input fields, to have something like

```
Curative 1 : X | Y
Curative 1 : A | B
```

The only way I found was using plain JavaScript, which looks like this:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('curative').length;
var target = document.getElementById('results');
var html = '';

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    html+= "<div class='row'>"
        +"<span class='col-md-6'>"+ items[i].getElementsByClassName('title')[0].html() +"</span>"
        +"<span class='col-md-6 curative_value'>"+ items[i].getElementsByClassName('equ')[0].html() +" | "+ items[i].getElementsByClassName('for')[0].html() +"</span>"
        +"</div>";
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this using Angular only?

Thanks

Comment: totally unable to understand what exactly you want... you dont have to write vanilla javascript code when you are using angular. plus you can write that html code in your ng repeat instead of making it through javascript method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add properties for `equ` and `for`, and use `ng-model` to bind to them:

Controller:

```
$scope.curatives = [
    {'name': 'Curative 1', 'equ': '', 'for': '' },
    {'name': 'Curative 2', 'equ': '', 'for': '' }
];
```

Template:

```
<div class="curative col-md-3" ng-repeat="c in curatives">
    <span class="title">{{c.name}}</span>
    <input class="equ" ng-model="c.equ" />
    <input class="for" ng-model="c.for" />
</div>

<div ng-repeat="c in curatives">
    {{ c.name }} : {{ c.equ }} | {{ c.for }}
</div>
```